# Clearing a double-precision buffer in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glsl

Is there a fast way to clear an OpenGL buffer with a double-precision data type or set a default value with an API call to avoid using a compute shader?

For half- and single-precision types, *glClearBufferData/glClearNamedBufferData* can be used, but it appears like there is no internal format enum for 64 bit types, which makes the switch from single- to double-precision data in scientific computing applications more cumbersome. Or am I missing an extension?

I am looking for a solution that works with OpenGL 4.6, Nvidia-specific extensions are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the day, a "double" is just a way of interpreting 64-bits of data. Your goal is to get the *right* 64-bits into your buffer.

As far as [buffer clearing](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Clearing) is concerned, the image format and pixel transfer parameters are just an explanation of how to interpret the data you pass. If the internal format of the clearing operation is `GL_RG32UI`, then each "pixel" in the buffer is 64-bits of data.

Given that, all you need to do is to get the clearing function to take a block of 64-bits and copy it exactly as you provide it. To do this, you have to use the right [pixel transfer parameters](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer).

See, pixel transfer operations can perform data conversion, taking the `data` pointer you pass and converting it to match the internal format. You don't want that; you want a direct copy. So your pixel transfer parameters need to exactly match the internal format. Which is quite easy.

A format of `GL_RG_INTEGER` represents a two-component pixel that stores integer data, in red-green order. And a type of `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` means that each component is a 32-bit unsigned integer. This exactly matches the internal format of `GL_RG32UI`, so the copying algorithm won't mess with the bytes of your data.

So, given some 64-bit `double` value in C or C++, clearing a buffer to that `double` ought to be as simple as:

```
void clear_buffer_to_double(GLuint buffer, double dbl)
{
  glClearNamedBufferData(buffer, GL_RG32UI, GL_RG_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &dbl);
}
```